# Reading data from the DataGridView just reads the last row c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I already could show the tooltip whenever the `quantity` less than `5` for that `productcode` bound with, but once the tooltip has been shown, it just read the last row of datagridview, not all of the datas inside it.

Here is the image:

[image]

From the above image, you can see there are two productcode that has a quantity less than 5, but if you see from the right bottom corner, it just show the last row of the data.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
void CheckQuantity()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string productCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value);

                if (quantity < 5)
                {
                    SystemManager.SoundEffect("C:/Windows/Media/Speech Off.wav");

                    customToolTip1.Show("- Product Code: " + productCode + "\n- Quantity: " + quantity, this, _screen.Right, _screen.Bottom, 5000);

                    timeLeft = 15;

                    _timer.Start();
                }

                else
                {
                    timeLeft = 15;

                    _timer.Start();
                }
            }
        }

void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeLeft--;

            if (timeLeft == 0)
            {
                _timer.Stop();

                CheckQuantity();
            }
        }

void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

void Database_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
       {
            _timer.Stop();
       }

uint timeLeft = 15;
```

I appreciate your answer.

Thanks.

Comment: you're re-showing your `customToolTip1` with each iteration of your loop

Comment: When your say "last column" do you mean "last row"?

Comment: @BenRobinson: Yeah, I mean last row. Sorry about that

Comment: @Jonesy: Could you please tell me how to do `re-showing with each iteration of loop`?

Comment: Also, why not just use a `timer` with an interval of 15 secs? When it ticks you call `CheckQuantity` instead of testing the time (I assume) every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear the result you are expecting, is this what you mean?

```
void CheckQuantity()
        {
            string msg = "";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string productCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value);
                if (quantity < 5)
                {
                    msg += "- Product Code: " + productCode + " - Quantity: " + quantity + "\n";
                }
            }
            if (msg != "")
            {
                SystemManager.SoundEffect("C:/Windows/Media/Speech Off.wav");
                customToolTip1.Show(msg, this, _screen.Right, _screen.Bottom, 5000);
            }
        }

void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            CheckQuantity();
        }

void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Interval = 15 * 1000;
            _timer.Start();
        }

void Database_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
       {
            _timer.Stop();
       }
```